# How to redirect with data

Tags: reactjs, next.js, backend

I would like to know if it is possible to redirect in nextJs while also passing data/props.

**Use Case:**

Someone uses an existing user's email to sign up, but the system recognizes it. It then offers to log in, and redirects the user to the login page, if they click on a link. Then, the email of the user would automatically be filled out, from the data passed through the redirect.

I know there is probably a way to do this by making a request, but would it be possible to do it in a concise manner, such as (as an example): `router.replace("/link", dataObj)`

Comment: Hmm I’m not an expert on new Next features but this sounds like a use case for session flashes. Or you could pass information using a query string

Comment: yeah query string seems like a really good solution, and I would probably be okay with that to be honest. Just curious if there's an actual feature for this. Thanks for the feedback!